# App UIs got defects when setMasksToBounds:YES

Tags: ipad, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I got a strange problem. You can see the two attached screenshots. The problem is the defects, unknown white rectangular defects. Some part of the keyboard even disappeared in the second screenshot.

Testing with device is the same problem...

Anyone knows what might be the reason? Thanks lot.

**textFieldDidBeginEditing**

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
DEBUGLog
if (!isIPAD) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    if (!viewFrameUp) {
        viewFrameUp=YES;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha=0;
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, -self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
      }


    CGPoint point = [textField.superview convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) toView:maintable];
    CGPoint contentOffset = maintable.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y=point.y-10.0-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height; // Adjust this value as you need
    [maintable setContentOffset:contentOffset];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


if ([cellTextFields indexOfObject:textField]==0) {
    [keyBoardControl setEnabled: NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [keyBoardControl setEnabled: YES forSegmentAtIndex:1]; 
} else{
    [keyBoardControl setEnabled: YES forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [keyBoardControl setEnabled: YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];   
}


}
```

[image: Normal Keyboard][image: Centred keyboard]

Comment: When does this happen? What are the steps leading up to these problems? Are you performing additional drawing after the keyboard appears?

Comment: thanks,I have updated the question with the textFieldDidBeginEditing. The App is universal, and I set tableview.contentOffset up and down for iPhone. Reproduce the problem will be: 1. push the viewcontroller, 2. select one UItextfield to edit. 3, change to another textfield to edit. THEN the Problem happens

Comment: What kind of object is your keyBoardControl?

Comment: Any error logs when you reproduce this? I'd recommend commenting out some code related to drawing, or hide/disable objects/controls in your xib files if you use them, until you're able to narrow down what's causing this.

Comment: Hi bneely,  I finally found the reason, the reason is one line of code:   [leftVC.view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES]; But still figuring how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone happened to come to this problem. I found the reason: I used the following CALayer's properties together to apply on the view's layer, which doesn't make any sense and cause me this UI problem..."masksToBounds:YES" shouldn't be used together with the shadows.

```
[myviewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES]

myviewLayer.shadowColor=...
myviewLayer.shadowOpacity=...
myviewLayer.shadowRadius=...
```